# How to evaluate html returned by a method within <td> tags in angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular8

I have method in `.ts` file that returns html to make button in td tag dynamically but using `<td>{{actions(rec1)}}</td>`, i get the html printed as [image: result] instead of dynamic buttons. Please suggest as how can this be achieved!

```
public actions(data) {
    let disabled = "";
    if (data.DASHBOARD_STATUS != "Failed" || data.addComment == 0) {
      if(data.addComment!=0 && this._defaultRegion == "APAC")
      {}
      else
      disabled = "disabled";
    }

    let hideCmt = "";
    if (data.addCommentAppConfig != "1") {
      hideCmt = "hidden";
    }

    let hideEmail = "";
    if (data.sendEmailAppConfig != "1") {
      hideEmail = "hidden";
    }
    else if (this._defaultRegion == "NAM") {
      if (data.DASHBOARD_STATUS == "Pending" || data.DASHBOARD_STATUS == "Incomplete")
        hideEmail = "hidden";
    }
    let hideDet = "";
    if (data.showDetailsAppConfig != "1") {
      hideDet = "hidden";
    }

    return '<button ' + hideCmt + ' id="btn_cmt" ' + disabled + ' class="DetailButton" style="margin-left:2px"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>' +
      '<button ' + hideDet + ' id="btn_detail" class="DetailButton" style="margin-left:2px"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>' +
      '<button ' + hideEmail + ' id="btn_eml" class="DetailButton" title="Email" ng-disabled="true"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do something similar only with react thanks to JSX.**

But not in Angular, maybe you should think about using element.append (yourHTML) or create an HTML template that binds the variables on the TS

```
const myHTML = '<div>Ciao</div>'

div.append(myHTML)
// OR
div.innerHTML(myHTML)
```

**Edited**

```
<td #actionsTd></td>
```

U need to return into a var your HTMLString in ur .ts

```
 const actionsHTML = this.actions()
```

And do this:

```
querySelector('#actionsTd').innerHTML = actionsHTML
```

This is the Javascript way!

But thanks to Angular u can to bind the variables like this:

```
<button [hidden]="isButtonHidden" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled"></button>
```

and in your .ts

```
public isButtonHidden = true;
public isButtonDisabled = this.calculateIfButtonIsDisabled();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Could you please suggest some code in my problem's context as i have to use <td> tag here.

Comment: Edited for you with love <3